# Find all values of $t$ such that $\det (t {I} - {A}) = 0$, where ${I}$ is the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus

Let
${A} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 5 & 7 \\ -2 & 7 & 7 \\ -1 & 1 & 4 \end{pmatrix}.$
Find all values of $t$ such that $\det (t {I} - {A}) = 0$, where ${I}$ is the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix.
I'm not sure where to start. I was thinking about writing it all out but then I realized I had no idea on what to do. Can I please get some tips and/or hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guide:

- Construct matrix $tI-A$.
- Compute determinant of $tI-A$, you might like to use [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion).
- If you do the above step correctly, you should get a cubic equation.
- Solve cubic equation.

Answer (score 0):

$t*\mathbb{I} = \begin{bmatrix}
                t & 0 & 0\\
                0 & t & 0\\
                0 & 0 & t\\
                 \end{bmatrix}$ and $t*\mathbb{I} - A = $ $\begin{bmatrix}
                                                            t & -5 & -7\\
                                                            2 & t-7 & -7\\
                                                            1 & -1 & t-4\\
                                                          \end{bmatrix}$

Now solve try to find the determinant by using guass-law which is easiest.

$t*(t-7)*(t-4) + (-5*-7*1) + (-7*2*-1) - (-7*(t-7)*1) - (t*-7*-1) - (-5*2*(t-4))$
 Solve this for $t$ and see for which value your equation becomes zero.

Or you can write your matrix like this by swapping rows:
$\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & -1 & t-4\\
  2 & t-7 & -7\\
  t & -5 & -7\\
  \end{bmatrix}$

$\overset{R2 -> R2-2R1/ R3 -> R3-tR1}{\longrightarrow} \begin{bmatrix}
                                                        1 & -1 & t-4\\
                                                        0 & t-5 & 1-2t\\
                                                        0 & t-5 & -7-t^2+4t\\
                                                      \end{bmatrix}$

$\overset{R3 -> R3-R2}{\longrightarrow} \begin{bmatrix}
                                            1 & -1 & t-4\\
                                            0 & t-5 & 1-2t\\
                                            0 & 0 & -t^2 +6t-8\\
                                             \end{bmatrix}$

$-t^2 + 6t -8 $ is zero if $t = 4 $ or $t =2 $ if one of the row of your matrix becomes zero then your determinant is zero.